# How do we know that one particular solution for the velocities of a two-body elastic collision is the correct one over the other?

Tags: momentum, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, collision

Assuming there is a 1-D collision between two bodies, having masses $m_1$ and $m_2$, if we conserve energy and momentum, we get two solutions.

$$
v_{1,i} = v_{1,f} \\
v_{2,i} = v_{2,f}
$$
or
$$
v_{1,i} = -v_{1,f} \\
v_{2,i} = -v_{2,f}
$$
Both of these are valid mathematical solutions under the conservation laws. If so, apart from practical experimentation, how do we decide which one of these is the correct answer? Is there an analysis that we should do locally within the system, rather than just using global laws?
**Note:** Subscripts i and f denote initial and final states.

Answer (score 4):

Conservation of Energy and Momentum alone does not give you a decision between the two options; it's the same with normal three-dimensional billiard balls.

Energy and momentum are conserved perfectly fine if the two billiard balls just pass 'magically' through each other and continue their movement unchanged. Still this doesn't happen.

You need to use further information, like the law that no two objects can be at the same place at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I mean the first solution would not change anything in the system at all after the collision right? So the two masses would just pass each other. Since you want to calculate the final state of a fully elastic collision, why would you consider the "not change a thing" solution?

Answer (score 1):

In 1 dimension, in the center-of-momentum frame, there are only 2 types of elastic scattering:

(1) Forward scattering:

$$ v'_i = v_i $$

for $i \in \{1, 2\}$ which looks like no collision at all.

(2) Backward scattering:

$$ v'_i = -v_i $$